# Get large icon from file extension

Tags: c#, wpf, icons, file-extension

There are several places that talk about how to get an icon from a file extension such as [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/fileicon.aspx) one and [this other](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GetFileTypeAndIcon.aspx) one. After several hours of playing around with this kind of projects I have managed to build something like:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {           
        System.Drawing.Icon temp = IconReader.GetFileIcon(".cs", IconReader.IconSize.Large, false);
        pictureBox1.Image = temp.ToBitmap();
    }
```

the execution of that button gets me:

[image]

but I am trying to actually get the large icon. Note how the icons on windows are much bigger:

[image]

How could I get that icon instead of the smaller one. I have spend so much time changing the other programs. Moreover I will like to make it work with wpf and most of the examples are with windows forms. I would appreciate if I can get an example of how to extract a files icon instead of modifying and entire project. If that is not possible that would still be very helpful and I will appreciate. It's just that I am not that good of a programmer and it took me a lot of time to modify the other examples.

Comment: Try manifesting your application to use common controls version 6 ("*xp themes enabled*"). It probably won't be the issue here; but there was an issue with the system image list api not returning the large icons unless v6 was used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a solution http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/filetoiconconverter.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The code you're referencing only uses 2 sizes:

```
public const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x000000000;     // get large icon
public const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001;     // get small icon
```

to get the extra_large size, you need to add your own define (and add another enum for calling functions):

```
public const uint SHGFI_EXTRALARGEICON = 0x000000002;     // get extra large icon
```

or if you just want a quick fix, replace `0x000000000` with `0x000000002` in the original large definition.

Here are all icon sizes:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make ShGetFileInfo return ExtraLarge and Jumbo icons.

Instead,

1) Call ShGetFileInfo with the SysIconIndex ( 0x000004000) flag  
2) Get the System Imagelist with the proper size using ShGetImageList
3) Get the HICON using ImageList_GetIcon and the .iIcon value from SHFILEINFO.